# Textview not displaying in custom viewgroup even when onMeasure() is called

Tags: java, android

So I am  just playing around in android and found something really strange. Before I states what is wrong let me give the code.

Here is my Custom Viewgroup code:

```
    package com.ayto.android.cleverpad;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    public class noteLayout extends ViewGroup {
    float leftOrientationSize = 0;
    float rightOrientationSize=0;
    public noteLayout(Context activityContext)
    {
        super(activityContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        RelativeLayout mainParent = (RelativeLayout) getParent();
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((mainParent.getWidth()/2)-30,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200,MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int numberOfChild = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0;i<numberOfChild;i++){
            View childView = getChildAt(i);
            float childHeight = (float) childView.getMeasuredHeight();
            float childWidth = (float) childView.getMeasuredWidth();
            RectF rect = new RectF();
            rect.bottom = childHeight+20;
            rect.top = 20;
            rect.left = 20;
            rect.right = childWidth+20;
            childView.layout((int) rect.left, (int) rect.top, (int) rect.right, (int) rect.bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the xml file that I add (`addView()`) to CustomView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/displayNoteTitle"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Test"
        android:id="@+id/displayNote"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_above="@+id/displayNoteTitle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/displayNoteTitle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/displayNoteTitle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So basically what I did was create an instance of my `noteLayout note = new noteLayout(getApplicationContext())` and use the layout inflater to inflate the views from my xml. Then I use `noteLayout.addView()` to add the inflated view into my custom viewgroup. My problem is that only the textview with the `android:Text = "Title"` is displayed and the other seem to not render. I am not so sure why this is the case.

[image]

> ActivityMain

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.widget.RelativeLayout; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
noteLayout test = new noteLayout(getApplicationContext()); 
test.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.Layout,null)); 
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity)).addView(test); 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); 
return true; 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will 
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long 
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml. 
int id = item.getItemId(); 

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement 
if (id == R.id.action_settings) { 
return true; 
} 

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
} 

}
```

Comment: Can you also include the code snippet for the activity? So I can try and replicate it in my IDE.

Comment: What you mean a snippet for the activity? All it is literally is a relative layout as parent another child relative layout and another textview called start. That shouldn't be too hard right? I would include my activity snippet if it was something complicated but really it is not. All I have in the activity is the default factory method and just a line for layout inflater and one more to instantiate my custom view. then another line using the addview method to add in what I inflated.

Comment: If you really insist on seeing my activity I will post it

Comment: Okay, I got confused.. The xml file you provided, is that the xml for the activity?

Comment: No that is just another layout I created separate from the activity. The activity layout is a relative layout. Oh I forgot to mention I also called addView() on my activity relative layout to add in my custom viewgroup and my custom viewgroup called addview to add in the xml I provided above. If you need further clarification plz tell me. I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: Sorry. That just confused me a lot more.. The xml you provided above.. should be added inside the Custom ViewGroup you did, and then the Custom ViewGroup is to be added to your MainActivity Relative Layout..? Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106303/discussion-between-sept-and-wowzer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So after our discussion, managed to see what was happening.. I'll explain it thoroughly as it might be confusing.. First of.. In the **MainActivity** the `noteLayout` was initialized like so:

> noteLayout test = new noteLayout(getApplicationContext());

and is then passed with another `RelativeLayout` that contains the 2 `TextView`s :

> ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity)).addView(test);

So now, the hierarchy would look like this:
RelativeLayout(activity_main)
-- RelativeLayout(one from xml)
---- TextView(title) 
---- TextView(body)

And in the code of `noteLayout` in `onMeasured()` this line appears:

> RelativeLayout mainParent = (RelativeLayout) getParent();

-- which means that the mainParent it gets is the RelativeLayout of the **MainActivity** (`R.layout.activity_main`), after that, the loop was made:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((mainParent.getWidth()/2)-30,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200,MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
        }
```

To verify this, I put a log inside the loop and it returns only 1 child. So what I did is modify the loop like so:

```
RelativeLayout mainParent = (RelativeLayout) getParent();
        final RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) getChildAt(0);
        child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((mainParent.getWidth() / 2) - 30, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((mainParent.getHeight() / 2) - 30, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        Log.d("SAMPLE", "RelativeLayout Child childcount: " + child.getChildCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < child.getChildCount(); i++) {
            Log.d("SAMPLE", "In loop: " + i);
            final View childOfChild = child.getChildAt(i);
            childOfChild.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((mainParent.getWidth() / 2) - 30, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
        }
```

You can see here that I treated the child of the first `RelativeLayout` as another `RelativeLayout` then made the loop using the `child.getChildCount()`. *Also (I just added default measure for the second RelativeLayout, you can edit it to whichever you prefer)*. This calls the `TextView`s properly now as to what you would expect from your code.

Here is a screenshot after running the code.

[image]

So overall. I just edited out the `onMeasure()` part of your code.. The main problem was just with which layout you were referring and looping. :D